# BLE scanForPeripheralsWithServices in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I am starting to play with BLE in Objective-C; I have a Nordic BLE device, with 1 service and a couple of characteristics.
Scanning with the method

`[manager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:nil options:nil];`

I got the service / characteristics:

```
Found Characteristic 'Unknown (<2a37>)' for service 'Unknown (<180d>)' 
Found Characteristic 'Unknown (<2a38>)' for service 'Unknown (<180d>)'
```

But scanning using :

```
[manager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:@"180d"]] options:nil];
```

I got no services. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: And if in the option you allow duplicate keys?

Comment: I don't understand the question...

Comment: And with `180D` (with upper "d")? Anyway, does this service appears in the advertisement data? If not, it's normal behavior.